# Windows Store App: Calling Async Method at Design Time

Tags: c#, windows, asynchronous, store, design-time

I'm experimenting with using d:DesignInstance to specify a fake data class to use for data binding at design time in a Windows Store app (win8.1).

I'm trying to initialize the fake data class from an embedded JSON file. However, it's only partly working. I call a LoadData() method from the constructor. This LoadData() is an async method, but it's called synchronously:

```
    public DesignTimePetitionInfo()
    {
        #pragma warning disable 4014
        LoadData();
        #pragma warning restore 4014
    }

    private async Task LoadData()
    {
        Uri dataUri = new Uri( "ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleData.json" );

        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync( dataUri );
        string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync( file );
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse( jsonText );

        URL = jsonObject.GetNamedString( "URL" );
        ChangeOrgID = Convert.ToInt32( jsonObject.GetNamedNumber( "ChangeOrgID" ) );
        Author = jsonObject.GetNamedString( "Author" );
        Content = jsonObject.GetNamedString( "Content" );

        JsonArray cities = jsonObject.GetNamedArray( "Communities" );

        foreach( JsonValue cityValue in cities )
        {
            JsonObject curCity = cityValue.GetObject();

            foreach( JsonValue sigValue in curCity.GetNamedArray( "Signatures" ) )
            {
                JsonObject sigObject = sigValue.GetObject();

                SignatureInfo curSig = new SignatureInfo( sigObject.GetNamedString( "Name" ),
                    sigObject.GetNamedString( "Reason" ) );

                CommunityInfo curComm = new CommunityInfo( sigObject.GetNamedString( "City" ),
                    sigObject.GetNamedString( "State" ), sigObject.GetNamedString( "Country" ) );

                CommunityInfo community = Communities.Where( c => c.CommunityID.Equals( curComm.CommunityID ) ).FirstOrDefault();
                if( community == null )
                {
                    community = curComm;
                    Communities.Add( community );
                }

                community.Signatures.Add( curSig );
            }
        }
    }
```

Interestingly, Communities gets populated in the designer window, so it looks like retrieving the Json file is working. However, the individual properties (e.g., URL) don't get set and their corresponding designer TextBlocks are empty.

But if I add the line

```
Author = "Some Name";
```

immediately after the call to LoadData() in the constructor the designer is updated to show "Some Name".

Is their a limitation on calling async methods at design time? Is there another way to access the embedded JSON file at design time?

Comment: The warning you suppress here, it's telling you something useful. Specifically, that you are calling an `async` method without `await` and so the method will return before the work is done. FWIW, when I try to create a simple sample, where I initialize a TextBlock's Text property in the constructor of my MainPage, that doesn't even work for me. I've found lots of things that work at run-time don't work in the designer for Windows Store apps, even when they would work in the designer for WPF programs. But it's hard to understand this scenario without a good, complete, concise code example.

Comment: I didn't mention that I also tried creating a manual completion event, and waiting on it for the load to complete. That didn't solve the problem. Which if it was just do to a timing issue it would have, I think.